# Jhipster - How not to override manual edits

Tags: jhipster

I know it is the most basic question. In the video tutorial you can see a change in one Java file http://www.jhipster.tech/video-tutorial/

This change was "a user can only see his projects, except if he is the admin". This is only a minor change and  works with the schema.

Now I want to extend the schema and I perform

a) only compatible changes (adding new tables and relation)

b) also some incompatible changes (e.g. fixing a typo in a table name)

My question: How does jHipsetr support such a evolution in the model with compatible and incompatible changes?

Regarding a) it should be possible to perform a kind of "merge" as you know the current model + changes and future model. Can this kind of evolution even be automated?

Regarding b) some things (like propagating table name changes) might even be possible to be automated

I am asking because I do not know how evolution in a model driven engineering approach is supported by jhipster.

Thank you for your answer,

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your manual changes, the `jhipster upgrade` [command](http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/) uses git to merge them with code evolutions in generator. Otherwise some coding conventions help a lot. You can see a [presentation (in French) from Altissia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOTjLOPXg48&feature=youtu.be&start=97m) about their coding conventions, [slides](https://github.com/AdrienHorgnies/altissia-jhipster-meetup-27-06-2017/raw/master/conventions/jhipster-meetup-9-intro-and-conventions.pptx) with code examples could be read by non French speaking people.